# Checking word inside a string in Coregraphe

Tags: python, pepper

I have to check with a [Python](https://www.python.org/) box if a word I've told to [Pepper](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-4/index.html) (saved externally from a dialog box) is inside a list (created as string,and saved into ALMemory from SSH in Matlab), and do something if yes or not.
How can I do this?

```
def onInput_onStart(self):
    #self.onStopped() #activate the output of the box
    picklist = ALProxy("ALMemory")
    list=picklist.getData("myFood")

def food(self):
    if food in list:
        tts=ALProxy("ALDialog")
        tts.say("Available")
```

Comment: Your code looks about right. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Yes, the robot doesn't tell 'Available'

Answer (score 0):

I personally would just manage it on the web using js, when it comes to this kind of stuff boxes give more trouble than it's worth. Raise an event with the string you want and check if the word is inside the list. After that you can either use the tts (as you seem to be trying to do) or raise and event (sending the true/false as a parameter) and use it to trigger whatever you want.

**Javascript:**

```
session = null
QiSession(connected, disconnected, location.host);
tts = null;
function connected(s) {
    console.log("Session connected");
    session = s;
    startSubscribe();

    session.service("ALTextToSpeech").then(function (t) {
        tts = t;
    });
}

function disconnected(error) {
    console.log("Session disconnected");
}

function startSubscribe() {
    session.service("ALMemory").then(function (memory) {
        memory.subscriber("toTablet").then(function (subscriber) {
            subscriber.signal.connect(functionThatChecks)
        });
    });
}

function functionThatChecks(word)
{
    tts.stopAll();
    /*Check if exists*/
    tts.say("It exists"); //Or raise an event
}
```

**Dialog**

```
u: (word) $eventName="word"
```

**Choregraphe**

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `self.list` before other functions can access it.
You also need to pass `users_food` to the function when you call food().
Assuming that `list` is a list of strings, and `users_food` is a string.

```
def onInput_onStart(self):
    #self.onStopped() #activate the output of the box
    picklist = ALProxy("ALMemory")
    self.list=picklist.getData("myFood")

def food(self, users_food):
    if users_food in self.list:
        tts=ALProxy("ALDialog")
        tts.say("Available")
```